# Change config file from magento 1 to magento 2

Tags: magento2, configuration

Facing this issue:

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class mygateway
>   does not exist

Don't know where I find this class in my module
Please help.

Here's my code:

> /home1/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Myname/Mygateway/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <payment>
            <mygateway>
                <debug>1</debug>
                <active>0</active>
                <model>mygateway/standard</model>
                <merchant_gateway_key backend_model="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted" />
                <order_status>pending</order_status>
                <title>My Gateway</title>
                <payment_action>sale</payment_action>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                <currency>Darham</currency>
                <debugReplaceKeys>MERCHANT_KEY</debugReplaceKeys>
                <paymentInfoKeys>FRAUD_MSG_LIST</paymentInfoKeys>
                <privateInfoKeys>FRAUD_MSG_LIST</privateInfoKeys>
                <frontName>mygateway</frontName>
                <helpers>Myname_Mygateway_Helper</helpers>
                <models>Myname_Mygateway_Model</models>
                <blocks>Myname_Mygateway_Block </blocks>
            </mygateway> 
      </payment>
    </default>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Issues like the one you mentioned can have several reasons. The following command sequence will check the dependencies and regenerates the code.

**Remove generated code pieces to make sure we have a clean workspace**

> rm -rf var/cache/* var/di/* var/generation/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/frontend/* vendor

**Install composer dependencies**

> composer install

**Compile DI Classes**

> php bin/magento setup:di:compile

**Compile Static Files**

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

**Set Permissions**

> chmod -R www-data:www-data && find app/code pub/static app/etc var/generation var/di var/view_preprocessed vendor ( -type f -or -type d ) -exec chmod u-w {} \; && chmod o-rwx app/etc/env.php && chmod u+x bin/magento

I hope it will help to solve your problem.

Comment: repo.magento.com)
username: where I got this username ????

Comment: It is your magento.com account.

Comment: how can i revert back it any command ?

Comment: i purchased my theme from envato i dont know username and password and my site is locked need composer install to run but i dint know username and passsword please help

Comment: What does mean by revert back? you can stop command execution by  `ctrl` + `c`

Comment: means this 
Autoload error
Vendor autoload is not found. Please run 'composer install' under application root directo

Comment: i dont want composer now how can i revert back my setting

Comment: For the composer install you don't need to Envato account detail, you need to magent.com account.

Comment: If you don't want composer then don't run `composer install` command :)

Comment: but my site or not opening it shows this error
Autoload error Vendor autoload is not found. Please run 'composer install' under application root directory

Comment: and from magento account i entered password and username aborting message show

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84325/discussion-between-chirag-patel-and-jhon-jhon-doe).